# Getting doubled value with an onPaste event on an input using React

Tags: reactjs, validation, input

I have a text input field in my React app and I want to validate its input so I have a validator function working in a handler for the onChange event. I also want to trim whitespace when a value is pasted into the input and then have that run through the onChange validator.

Currently my JSX looks like this:

```
handleChange(event) {
    let { name, value } = event.target
    if (typeof this.props.validatorFunction === "function") {
        value = this.props.validatorFunction(value) // the validator function in this case is {value => value.replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase()}
    }
    this.setState({
        [name] : value
    })
}

handlePaste(event) {
    let { name, value, selectionStart, selectionEnd } = event.target
    let pastedValue = event.clipboardData.getData("text")
    let pre = value.substring(0, selectionStart)
    let post = value.substring(selectionEnd, value.length)
    value = (pre + pastedValue + post).trim()
    this.setState({
        [name] : value
    })
}

render() {  
    return (
        <input type="text" name="myInput" value={this.state.myInput} onChange={this.handleChange} onPaste={this.handlePaste}></input>
    )
}
```

Regular typing works as expected however, when I paste something such as "test string" I get "test-stringtest string". "test String " with the trailing white-space I get "test-stringtest string ". This works except for the doubling up of the untrimmed but somehow lowercased but not replaced original string. How do I fix this, or what is the proper workflow for this kind of validation using React controlled components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, I am providing more details on the solution.

It turns out that for my purpose, having an `onPaste` handler is superfluous. If I removed the `onPaste` handler, the doubling issue would be resolved, and paste behaviour inherently remains. An example of the code I would write for this today is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tvandinther/sLav0chj/31/

```js
function ValidatedInput(props) {

  const format = (value) => typeof props.formatFunction === "function"
    ? props.formatFunction(value)
    : value

  return (
    <input
      value={props.value} 
      onChange={event => props.setValue(format(event.target.value))}
      />
  )
}
```

Suppose you do need to keep the `onPaste` handler. In that case, the solution described is to call your shared logic (in this case, formatting the string and setting the state) in both `onPaste` and `onChange` handlers but ensure that `event.preventDefault()` is called in the `onPaste` handler.

Answer (score 8):

You need to call `event.preventDefault()` after handling your paste event.  As it is, the paste event is changing the state in `handlePaste` and then going on to add the pasted text to the input, triggering `handleChange`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew onChange was being triggered again but I thought that was going to just cause the input to be validated like I wanted it to. This wasn't so.

Instead I moved the validation from the handleChange method to a validate method and called that from both handlers separately and incorporated the event.preventDefault()

Comment: @tvandinther can you please post your solution here as an answer?

Comment: @Ram I posted a follow-up.